# "Lifetime" of a channel variable created by openwriter()

Tags: file, parameter-passing, chapel

The following code is another attempt to make a class with a channel. Here, I am passing a channel directly from the caller side rather than opening it inside a class. While the code gives the expected result, I am wondering if it is legitimate to do such a thing, particularly by calling `openwriter()` directly in the `new` statement (as in the case of `baa`). In other words, is it OK to assume that the file remains open as long as there exists a variable (here `output` in `Myclass`) that references the underlying file, even when the actual channel variable is temporary?

```
class Myclass
{
    var output: channel;
    proc init( output = stdout )
    {
        this.output = output;
    }
}

proc main()
{
    var foo = new owned Myclass();
    foo.output.writeln( 10 );   // written to stdout

    var baa = new owned Myclass( openwriter("test.out") );
    baa.output.writeln( 20 );   // written to file
    baa.output.writeln( 30 );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should continue to work because files and channels are reference counted.

See also https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#functions-for-closing-channels

Also, note that at the current time, temporary variables in Chapel are destroyed at the end of the enclosing block (rather than at the end of the statement, which is what C++ does). It wouldn't matter in this case, since the channel's reference count would be increased in the MyClass initializer before the statement `var baa = ...` completes. This can occasionally be surprising (see https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/11492 ) and so is something we are considering adjusting (see https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/11534 ).

Comment: Thanks very much! It is good to know about reference counting of channel, and also the fact that temporaries are not destroyed per statement (indeed, I imagined the opposite...)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your code should be fine as-is.  The documentation for files and channels indicates that they are reference counted so that as long as some variable is referring to them, they should stay alive.  The following quote is from the version 1.19 documents on [Functions for Closing Channels](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#functions-for-closing-channels):

> Files and channels are reference counted. Each file and channel is closed automatically when no references to it remain. For example, if a local variable is the only reference to a channel, the channel will be closed when that variable goes out of scope. Programs may also close a file or channel explicitly.

Comment: Thanks very much, the answer is written so clearly in the online document... XD (I will read the page more carefully.) Although there are two answers, I will accept the other one because it has a bit more information. But thanks again :)